# How to write Python script as Amazon Lambda function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-lambda

I want to write the Python script below as Amazon lambda function, the script publish RabbitMQ metrics to Amazon cloudwatch, I've tried several times and managed to get rabbitmq depths but my Lambda function failed to publish metrics to cloudwatch.

```
from __future__ import with_statement, print_function
from pyrabbit.api import Client
import boto3
import os

host = ""
username = ""
password = ""
vhost = ""
namespace = ""

def get_queue_depths(host, username, password, vhost):
    cl = Client(host, username, password)
    if not cl.is_alive():
       raise Exception("Failed to connect to rabbitmq")
    depths = {}
    queues = [q['name'] for q in cl.get_queues(vhost=vhost)]
    for queue in queues:
       if queue == "aliveness-test":
          continue
       if 'celery' in queue:
          continue
       depths[queue] = cl.get_queue_depth(vhost, queue)
    return depths

def publish_queue_depth_to_cloudwatch(cwc, queue_name, depth, namespace):
    float(depth)
    cwc = boto3.client('cloudwatch',region_name="us-east-1")
    response = client.put_metric_data(
        Namespace=namespace,
        MetricData=[ { 'MetricName': queue_name, 'Value': depth, 'Unit': 'Count' } ]
)
print("Putting metric namespace=%s name=%s unit=Count value=%f" %
    (namespace, queue_name, depth))

def publish_depths_to_cloudwatch(depths, namespace):
    for queue in depths:
        publish_queue_depth_to_cloudwatch(cwc, queue, depths[queue], namespace)

def get_queue_depths_and_publish_to_cloudwatch(host, username, password, vhost, namespace):
    depths = get_queue_depths(host, username, password, vhost)
    publish_depths_to_cloudwatch(depths, namespace)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        get_queue_depths_and_publish_to_cloudwatch(host, username, password, vhost, namespace)
```

Comment: So the specific question is about publishing to CloudWatch from your Lambda function? What was the error message in the Lambda function's CloudWatch log when it failed to publish metrics to CloudWatch? Is the Lambda function running inside or outside of your VPC? Did you assign the proper IAM role to the function that would allow it to publish metrics to CloudWatch?

Comment: well my lambda function manages to get rabbitmq depths i can see them in the log but when it comes to publishing to cloudwatch it fails and exits with a timeout, the function is running in a VPC and yes i assigned the proper IAM role to the function

Comment: If it is running in a VPC then you will have to add a NAT Gateway to your VPC in order for the Lambda function to have access to anything outside the VPC, including AWS resources like CloudWatch.

Comment: It works thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by adding a NAT gateway to the VPC in order for the lambda function to get access to Aws resources. As suggested by Mark B in the comment